# firefox: input field color

Tags: firefox, linux

The input filed color in my Firefox is light gray on white background, which obviously is unreadable. I am using a dark theme, and firefox seems to take over the text color, while keeping its white background.

Anyway, I was wondering if I could change it, so that firefox uses black color for the input field text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create/edit `~/.mozilla/firefox/YOUR-PROFILE/chrome/userContent.css` so it includes:

```
input, textarea {
   color:#000 !important;
}
```

personally I also like to ensure that the background is white, and make the text a dark grey so it's softer, so I have mine set to:

```
input, textarea {
   color:#555 !important;
   background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Note: You'll need to quit and restart Firefox before the changes show up.

Comment: that works great, thank you so much. Your solution is elegant and simple. And I don't need to install any addons.

Comment: I have [one more related question](http://superuser.com/questions/763196/force-text-background-color-in-drop-down-menu-in-firefox)

Comment: FYI If there is no chrome directory there, just create it. Don't use the other ones in the subpaths.

Comment: An alternative to editing userContent.css, which doesn't requiring restarting Firefox every time you edit the style, is writing a style for the [Stylish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Comment: @mic That is also a good idea, but note that Stylish will not help with any fields within Firefox itself, like userContent.css and userChrome.css will.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use a Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name           Style Corrector
// @author         Nufros (loosely based on Color Corrector by Erik Nomitch)
// @description    Style Corrector (by Nufros) allow you to edit colors, (...)
// @namespace      userscripts.org/scripts/show/36850
// @include        *
// @exclude        http://*.deviantart.com/*
// @exclude        http://*.myspace.tld/*
// @exclude        http://*.youtube.tld/*
// ==/UserScript==

// Visit the script's page for the full script

GM_addStyle("input { color: #bfbfbf; background-color: #222222 !important; }");
GM_addStyle("textarea { color:#bfbfbf; background-color: #222222 !important;}");
```

Comment: could you please be more specific, as to how I should "use Greasemonkey script" ? I have no idea what that means

Comment: 1. install the greasemonkey addon. 2. install the above script. [This kid has figured it out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAJngjAx_5o), if you need more details.