# Force text/background color in drop-down menu in Firefox

Tags: firefox, colors, css

I have following code in my `userContent.css`, which forces all textareas and input fields to be black on white:

```
input, textarea {
    color:#000  !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;

}
```

I need a similar trick for drop-down menus, but i am unable to find the correct keyword.

At the moment, drop-down menus on some websites have white text on white background, which makes them unreadable. I need top enforce my colors.

## UPDATE:

I have added `select` to my definitions:

```
select, input, textarea {
    color:#000  !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;

}
```

This works for most websites, but on few websites this does not work, for example [here](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10430349/mfg_partno/JD097C). Using DOM inspector, I can see that the search field is of type `input`, but for some reason, it still has black on black color. I.e. it ignores my settings. How can I override the settings for all websites?

Comment: `<select>` - [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: I'm on Firefox on Windows and both with and without the custom css your example site has [black on white search bars.](https://i.imgur.com/r8BD6mA.png)